# Debian Buster: 'E: Unable to locate package'

Tags: linux, apt, debian-buster

I have a new install of Debian Buster, I downloaded the ProtonVPN CLI package and went to install and got the errors:

```
E: Unable to locate package protonvpn-stable-release_1.0.0-1_all.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'protonvpn-stable-release_1.0.0-1_all.deb'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'protonvpn-stable-release_1.0.0-1_all.deb'
```

my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file looks like this:

```
#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.10.0 _Buster_ - Official amd64 NETINST 20210619-16:11]/ buster main

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 10.10.0 _Buster_ - Official amd64 NETINST 20210619-16:11]/ buster main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main

deb http://security.debian.org.debian-security buster/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org.debian-security buster/updates main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main
```

I was able to `apt-get install wget` as well as `update` and `upgrdade`.  I even tried uncommenting the `cdrom` lines at the top.  I reran `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`.

Still, when I try to install the ProtonVPN package I get the above errors.

**Note** I understand that this is not strictly programming related.  If there is a more appropriate stack, please let me know in comments and I will close and post there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install manually downloaded Debian package, use `dpkg`:

`dpkg -i protonvpn-stable-release_1.0.0-1_all.deb`

If `dpkg` is complaining about missing dependencies, then use `apt-get -f install` after running `dpkg`